# Checking if an array B has an element that is greater than an Element in array A, array are not fo equal length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays,(A and B) of different length. The goal is to evaluate whether B has an element that is greater than any element in A. Then push the element returned to a newarray.

I have tried a for loop through each array, then pushed the result to a newarray but the result is always undefined.

```
var A=[1,2,3];
var B=[4,1,6];

function getGreatervalue()
     {
            for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++);
            for (var j=0;j<B.length;j++);
             if(B[j]<A[i]){
        var newarray=[];
            newarray.push(B[j]);
            console.log(newarray);
         }
          }getGreatervalue()

           expected result
            new array=,[4,6];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring new array every time condition is satisfied, also there are some corrections and below is my version.

```
var newarray=[];
var A=[1,2,3];
var B=[4,1,6];
function getGreatervalue()
{
    for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++)
    {       
        for (var j=0;j<B.length;j++)
        {           
            if(B[j]>A[i])
            {
                if(newarray.indexOf(B[j]) == -1)
                {
                    newarray.push(B[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newarray;
}
var result=getGreatervalue();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. The code loops every `B` for each `A`, while it should loop over every `A` for each `B`. Otherwise, You will either the first element that satisfies the condition in B repeatedly added to your result (if you use a `break`) or, if you don't, for every `A`, every `B` that is smaller than that element will be added to the result. So, check for each `B`, every `A`.
2. You are redefining your results array `newarray` every time the condition is satisfied, which throws out your previous results. The results array must be defined outside of the loop.
3. Your condition is `B[j] < A[i]` which is contrary to your requirement, which is, and I quote: "whether B has an element that is greater than any element in A."

```js
const A=[1,2,3];
const B=[4,1,6];

function getGreatervalue() {
  const result = []
  for(let i=0;i<B.length;i++) {
    for (let j=0;j<A.length;j++) {
      if(B[i]>A[j]){
        result.push(B[i])
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
}

getGreatervalue();

//  expected result
//   new array=,[4,6];
```

Here's another version using more modern features with the same result:

```js
const newarray=[];
const A=[1,2,3];
const B=[4,1,6];
function getGreatervalue()
{
 return B.filter(bEl => A.some(aEl => bEl > aEl))
}


const result = getGreatervalue()
console.log(result);

//  expected result
//   new array=,[4,6];
```

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is to evaluate whether B has an element that is greater than any element in A

So Find the minimum value in A and filter B

```js
var A=[1,2,3];
var B=[4,1,6];

function getGreatervalue(){
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, A)
  return B.filter(num=>num>min)
}
console.log(getGreatervalue())
```